# Do all primes $p$ except 2 and 3 divide the sum of the squares of integers from 0 to $p - 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I stumbled upon this relationship while working on a completely unrelated problem, and upon testing it for all primes less than 100, it was true. I figure that this is not a coincidence; I just don't have the number theory background to see why it's true, and it's not really something you can google. Here is the proposition formally:

All primes $p$ except 2 and 3 divide the sum of the squares of the integers from 0 to $p - 1$: $$p|\sum_{i = 0}^{p - 1} i^2$$

Answer (score 2):

It is true because 
$$1^2+2^2+\cdots+(p-1)^2=\frac{(p-1)p(2p-1)}{6}.$$
Now the condition $p>3$ implies your statement.

Comment: And the condition that $p$ is prime, of  course...